# Runtime Error (Tolerance of 0.00010999999999999899 reached. Failed to converge after 1 iterations, value is 0.10011.(

Tags: python, optimization, finance

I'm trying to calculate the TIR from the cashflow of some Tickers. When I execute this functions i have some errors:

```
def xnpv(rate, cashflows):
    chron_order = sorted(cashflows, key=lambda x: x[0])
    t0 = chron_order[0][0]  # t0 is the date of the first cash flow

    return sum([cf/(1+rate)**((t-t0).days/365.0) for (t, cf) in chron_order])


def xirr(cashflows, guess=0.01):

    return optimize.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r, cashflows), guess)*100


def tir(cashflow, precio, plazo=1):
    flujo_total = [(datetime.datetime.today() +
                    datetime.timedelta(days=plazo), -precio)]
    for i in range(len(cashflow)):
        if cashflow.iloc[i, 0].to_pydatetime() > datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=plazo):
            flujo_total.append(
                (cashflow.iloc[i, 0].to_pydatetime(), cashflow.iloc[i, 1]))

    return round(xirr(flujo_total, guess=0.1), 2)
```

This is the Error:

```
> Tolerance of 0.00010999999999999899 reached. Failed to converge after 1 iterations, value is 0.10011.
> File "C:\Users\armartinof\OneDrive - Tetra Pak\Documents\Varios\Inversiones\Dashboard.py", line 28, in xirr
> return optimize.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r, cashflows), guess)*100
> File "C:\Users\armartinof\OneDrive - Tetra Pak\Documents\Varios\Inversiones\Dashboard.py", line 39, in tir
> return round(xirr(flujo_total, guess=0.1), 2)
> File "C:\Users\armartinof\OneDrive - Tetra Pak\Documents\Varios\Inversiones\Dashboard.py", line 122, in <module>
> tir_j = tir(cashflows[j], Data_ON.loc[j, 'Precio_dolares'], plazo=1)
> RuntimeError: Tolerance of 0.00010999999999999899 reached. Failed to converge after 1 iterations, value is 0.10011.
>
```

Do you know if there is some Walkaround to make the code continuous and that it doesn't stop when it makes the calculations?

I think that the issue is when i have only 1 row in the cashflow. But i don't know how to correct the code to resolve this issue.